# Can i use TortoiseSVN 1.7.9 with Subversion 1.8

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am currently using TortoiseSVN 1.7.12 and it says our Subversion is 1.7.9.  Can I upgrade my TortoiseSVN client to the latest 1.8 even though the website says 1.8 is linked to svn 1.8, without upgrading the svn server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup.

Unfortunately, I can't do a one word answer, so...

You can use almost any version of a Subversion client with almost any version of the server. Some servers might prevent you from using client revisions earlier than 1.5 since SVN 1.5 added merge tracking and earlier clients cannot handle that.

This may change when Subversion 2.0 comes out.

Comment: Bugger.  I did that but know it says I have to upgrade my folders as they are in an old version.  So I guess that means other users will have to have the same version on their pc as well?

Comment: @dreza You may have to upgrade your LOCAL working directory if you upgrade. I believe 1.7 made a major change in the structure of the local working directory by consolidating all the `.svn` folders into the root of the working directory. You have to do is be careful when using the same local working directory with different SVN clients. Since the checked out directory isn't necessarily compatible between clients. For example trying to use the command line client with the Eclipse client or TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Cheers for the comments.  I think I get it a bit clearer now and have jumped in and just upgraded all my local copies :)

Comment: This is wrong. See my comment but no subversion client will support both 1.7 and 1.8 at the same time.

Comment: @Frederic I was answering the question of whether a particular version of a Subversion server needs a particular version of a Subversion client. The answer is no. I can use almost any version of a SVN client with almost any version of SVN the server is running. A 1.8 SVN client will work fine on a 1.7 SVN server. What you are referring to is the ***checked out working directory***. You are correct that you cannot use a 1.7 client on a working directory checked out by a 1.8 client.

Comment: Moreover, from my experience, you better keep the svn client and server alike because a commit with a wrong version could create some problems server side.

Comment: I tell users to make sure all of their Subversion clients are all on the same major version, so they can use them interchangeably on the same working directory. However, I don't tell them they need the same version for the server. This can be impossible if they connect to multiple servers. What if one server is on 1.8 and another is on 1.7? Do the users need to uninstall and reinstall SVN clients to keep clients to the same version? There is no problem with a client on one version and a server on another.

Answer (score 0):

No subversion client will support both 1.7 and 1.8 at the same time, although you can have multiple versions of command line clients installed. Unfortunately that is not possible with shell extensions such as TortoiseSVN. So bottom line is, don't upgrade to 1.8 until all your subversion tools are at 1.8.

It's explained here : [Issue 518:   v1.8 not supporting svn 1.7 format on Windows-7 64-bit SP1](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/issues/detail?id=518)

Comment: This is a CLIENT issue. You can't mix 1.7 and 1.8 clients in the same working directory. There is no issue using a 1.8 client with a 1.7 server or visa versa. Otherwise, you'd have to uninstall and reinstall clients if you talk to two different Subversion servers on two different versions